# An expression for non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'order'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need an expression for non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'order'.

```
SELECT   Kelas.idkelas           AS id_kelas,
         Matakuliah. Mata kuliah AS nama_matakuliah,
         Dosen. Nama             AS nama _dosen,
         COUNT(krs.idkelas)      AS jumlah_peserta
FROM     kelas,
         matakuliah,
         dosen,
         krs
WHERE    kelas. Idkelas = krs.idkelas
         AND kelas.nip = dosen.nip
         AND kelas.kode = matakuliah.kode
         AND krs. nilai IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY kelas.idkelas,
         matakuliah.Matakuliah,
         dosen. Nama
HAVING   COUNT(krs.idkelas)
ORDER BY kelas.Id kelas
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HAVING` requires a boolean expression.  So something like:

```
SELECT   Kelas.idkelas           AS id_kelas,
         Matakuliah. Mata kuliah AS nama_matakuliah,
         Dosen. Nama             AS nama _dosen,
         COUNT(krs.idkelas)      AS jumlah_peserta
FROM     kelas,
         matakuliah,
         dosen,
         krs
WHERE    kelas. Dikelas = krs.idkelas
         AND kelas.nip = dosen.nip
         AND kelas.kode = matakuliah.kode
         AND krs. nilai IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY kelas.idkelas,
         matakuliah.Matakuliah,
         dosen.Nama
HAVING   COUNT(krs.idkelas) > 0
ORDER BY kelas.Id
```

Comment: thanks david browne - Microsoft